# cron not running on ubuntu 16.04 laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I have php 7.2 installed in ubuntu 16.04. (/usr/bin/php7.2 is there not /usr/bin/php)

I have set following commnad to rub cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 
2>&1
```

or should I write below command

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

yestreday, I kill cron process to stop running cron and started again with following command

```
sudo service cron restart
```

but somehow, cron is not  running automatically.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: it could be an issue of `permissions` given to `folder` or `file`.

Comment: What is the output of `service cron status`?

Comment: Active is the status @l'L'l

Comment: to which folder or file, should I check permission @Gulshan

Comment: @SanjayPrajapati: You mentioned you are using php 7, but your `cron` command does not reflect that. It should be `* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.2 ...`

Comment: it was setup with `/usr/bin/php` beofre and was working well. @l'L'l